# Definning Ant task from Ivy dependency

Tags: java, ant, ivy, build.xml

I'm using IvyDE to manage my project dependencies and Ant to build my project and perform some other tasks.

So my `ivy.xml` file looks like this:

```
<ivy-module version="2.0">
<info organisation="test" module="test" revision="0-RELEASE"/>
<dependencies>
    <dependency org="com.generator" name="Generator" rev="2.0-RELEASE" />
</dependencies>
</ivy-module>
```

I want to define a new task in my `build.xml` file, something like this:

```
<taskdef name="generate" classname="com.Generator" />
```

Where the class com.Generator is packed in the ivy dependency.

Now the `taskdef` declaration would not compiled, this is because I did not set the `classpath` for the class.

My question is, if it is possible to refer to the ivy dependency from the `build.xml` file so I can define the new task ?

Thank you
Gilad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can:

The best way is to add an own configuration and its dependency for the task in your `ivy.xml` file:

```
<configuration>
  <conf name="generator" visibility="private"/>
</configuration>

<dependencies>
  …
  <dependency org="com.generator" 
      name="Generator" rev="2.0-RELEASE" 
      conf="generator->default"/>
</dependencies>
```

Then you can use it in your `build.xml`:

```
<ivy:cachepath pathid="generator.classpath" 
    conf="generator" log="quiet"/>
<taskdef name="generate" 
    classname="com.Generator" 
    classpathref="generator.classpath"/>
```

You need the ivy task defined to do so!